# Open / Read .evt Files From Another Computer

Tags: windows-xp, event-log

I'd like to open and read Windows Event Log files. The files will be copied from a non-functioning install of Windows XP SP3 and I'd like to read them from a totally different install of Windows XP SP3 on a totally different computer. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

-Right click on My Computer, choose Manage

-Right click on Event Viewer, choose Open Log File

-Browse to .evt file, select, and click on Open